# How to pass UTC timezone for APScheduler 3.0?

Tags: python, heroku, apscheduler

Any Heroku folks on here? It seems their system will not execute things from APScheduler labeled as cron. FYI: I'm using the free package. Using this example, the interval will run, the cron will not. Has anyone else run into this?

EDIT: Its been suggested that I specify UTC I am unsure how to do that using add_job. Any takers? Because I know this isn't currently right:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from pytz import utc

sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone=utc)

def grabit():
    print "This job is run every weekday"

def tick():
    print "every 5 minutes"

sched.add_job(grabit, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=0, minute=13, id="get_things", replace_existing=True)
sched.add_job(tick, 'interval', minutes=5)
sched.start()
```

Answer (score 19):

You can pass the string like this:

```
sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone="Asia/Kolkata")
```

And find the string using thisL

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
tz = get_localzone()
print(tz)
```

The object will contain the string

Answer (score 0):

Update to dark Knight's solution:

```py
from tzlocal import get_localzone
tz = get_localzone()
print(tz)
```

Output:

```
Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: Hi Manoj, welcome to stackoverflow.  It's not clear to me how this answers the question being asked.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Thank you demented hedgehog for the warm welcome.
I came across this and thought of adding an update, I found to the dark Knight's solution.